# finding coords of points along a circumference

Tags: python, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I'm trying to make a clock, and I'm trying to draw the second, minute and hour hand according to the present time, getting it from

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Is there an algorithm for finding the coords of a circle when you have the:

radius,

circumference length,

and length of circumference taken up (worked out with the following:)

```
circumference = math.pi * (2 * radius)
secs = 10           # for example
secs /= 60          # gets fraction of clock face taken up i.e. for hours I would use /24
secs *= circumference
```

or do I have to work it out using angles according to each quarter of the clock?

thanks

Comment: Better using the angles, since you could easily place it in cartesian.

Answer (score 1):

The point coordinates are better calculated from an angle; then you need to add the canvas coordinates of the location of the circle center.

```
x = radius * math.cos(angle) + center_x
y = radius * math.sin(angle) + center_y
```

An example here that shows moving points on the circumference of a circle: http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_zoPm59Qeb1_1.py

```
import simplegui
import math


radius = 50
offset = 0

def draw(canvas):
    global offset
    canvas.draw_circle([100,100], radius, 2, "Red")
    offset = (offset + 1) % 12
    for t in range(offset, 360+offset, 12):
        angle = t * math.pi / 180
        canvas.draw_circle([radius * math.cos(angle) + 100, radius * math.sin(angle) + 100], 2, 2, 'yellow')

frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 200, 200)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

frame.start()
```